# Finding the matrix representation of a linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V=\left \{ A\in M_2\left(\mathbb{C} \right )\mid \text{tr}(A)=0 \right \}$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ defined by $T\left(A\right)=\left(3\,\mathrm{i}-2\right)A+\left(4-6\,\mathrm{i}\right)A^t$
>   Find the matrix representation of $T$ with regard to the basis $B=\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)\right\}$

What I have done is to plug the basis vectors (in this case matrices) to the transformation:

$$T(\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}3i-2&0\\0&2-3i\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}4-6i&0\\0&-4+6i\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2-3i&0\\0&-2+3i\end{pmatrix}$$

$$T(\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}0&3i-2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\4-6i&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&3i-2\\4-6i&0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$T(\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\3i-2&0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&4-6i\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&4-6i\\3i-2&0\end{pmatrix}$$

So the matrix is the sum? 
$$\begin{pmatrix}2-3i&2-3i\\2-3i&3i-2\end{pmatrix}$$

Or should I put them as as vector columns?

Comment: No, the space $V$ is three-dimensional (the basis has three elements), so obviously the matrix that you seek is of size $3 \times 3$.

Comment: @HansLundmark but I get 3 matrices (3 basis vectors), should I add them up to one matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the matrix is the matrix whose columns are the images. You need to find the images, and rewrite them as coordinate vectors with respect to $B$.

$$T(B_1) = (2-3i)B_1 + 0B_2 + 0B_3$$

$$T(B_2) = 0B_1 + (-2+3i)B_2 + (4-6i)B_3$$

$$T(B_3) = 0B_1 + (4-6i)B_2 + (-2+3i)B_3$$

Therefore

$$[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 2-3i & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -2+3i & 4-6i\\ 0 & 4-6i & -2+3i\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks I have forget the part of coordinate vectors with respect to the basis, but how did you get a matrix of 3 by 3 and not 4 by 4?

Comment: Matrix representations are matrices whose columns are coordinate vectors. $B$ has three vectors, so the columns will have three entries.

Comment: Sorry that I can not see it, but yes we have 3 basis vectors but they are 2 by 2 or 1 by 4/ 4 by 1

Comment: It doesn't matter if they were $100\times 100$ matrices. If there are three of them in $B$, the matrix $[T]_B$ is $3\times 3$

Comment: I know, you are 100% right it is just that I can't see why, I see the basis vectors as:

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$  ,$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$  ,
$\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ so I get 4 by 3 matrix

Comment: For example, if $B=\{(0,4,2,1,1),(0,0,2,1,1\}$ and $T(a,b,c,d,e)=(0,b,a,0,0)$, we have $T(B_1) = (0,4,0,0,0) =4B_1 + (-1)B_2$ and $T(B_2) = (0,0,0,0,0) =0B_1 + 0B_2$. So $$[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0\\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$